# Clickhouse: Cannot connect to a kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I am trying to setup a materialzed view on top of clickhouse through the kafka integration. Unfortunately I am unable to connect to the brokers that I want to read from. Here is the message I get

```
Jun 20 20:48:00 ip-172-31-27-24 clickhouse-server[3280]: %3|1529527680.456|ERROR|ClickHouse 1.1.54380#consumer-1| [thrd:<some-dns>:9094/bootstrap]: <some-dns>:9094/bootstrap: Receive failed: Disconnected
```

I tried to ping the aforementioned dns server from that machine that I have installed clickhouse and that worked.
I am also using SSL/SCRAM. Here is the relevant part of the config.xml:

```
<kafka>
    <sasl_mechanisms>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanisms>
    <sasl_username>some_user</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>some_pass</sasl_password>
</kafka>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: ping is not enough, what says `nc -vz <some-dns> 9094` ?

Comment: Try to include the kafka broker IP's in the hosts file